# MySQL Inner Join problem - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I am building a database for a hotel booking system and I'm trying to create an inner join to link my Property to the Facilities. I just want to show what property has what facilities. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? Have been trying different variations to no avail. The first block of code here I received error message #1066 - Not unique table/alias (for whatever table I reference in "FROM", it says this)

```
SELECT DB_Property.Name, DB_Facilities.Facility, DB_PropertyFacilities.PropertyID
FROM DB_Property
INNER JOIN DB_Property ON DB_Facilities.Facility = DB_Property.Facility
INNER JOIN DB_Facilities ON DB_PropertyFacilities.FacilitiesID = DB_Facilities.FacilitiesID
WHERE DB_Property.Name = 'The Ampersand Hotel';
```

For the following attempt, I got the error message #1054 - unknown column 'DB_PropertyFacilities.FacilitiesID' in 'on clause'

```
SELECT DB_Property.Name FROM DB_Property
INNER JOIN DB_Facilities ON DB_PropertyFacilities.FacilitiesID = DB_Facilities.FacilitiesID
WHERE DB_Property.Name = 'The Ampersand Hotel'
```

I successfully created an Inner Join earlier today and it's driving me crazy that I can't get this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why do you have `DB_Property` twice, in both `FROM` and `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: What is `DB_PropertyFacilities`?

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Barmar, your first attempt has `DB_Property` twice, once in the the `SELECT` once in a `JOIN`. That doesn't look right, you probably need to fix this query.

In your second attempt, table alias `DB_PropertyFacilities` is not defined in your query. You probably meant `DB_Property` instead:

```
SELECT DB_Property.Name 
FROM DB_Property
INNER JOIN DB_Facilities ON DB_Property.FacilitiesID = DB_Facilities.FacilitiesID
WHERE DB_Property.Name = 'The Ampersand Hotel'
```

I would also recommend using table aliases to make the query somehow more readable:

```
SELECT p.Name 
FROM DB_Property p
INNER JOIN DB_Facilities f ON p.FacilitiesID = f.FacilitiesID
WHERE p.Name = 'The Ampersand Hotel'
```

Comment: This has the same problem of using `DB_Property` twice without giving it an alias, so it's ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the join with `DB_PropertFacilities`.

```
SELECT p.Name, f.Facility, p.PropertyID
FROM DB_Property AS p
INNER JOIN DB_PropertFacilities AS pf ON pf.PropertyID = p.PropertyID
INNER JOIN DB_Facilities AS f ON f.FacilitiesID = pf.FacilitiesID
WHERE p.Name = 'The Ampersand Hotel';
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Can I ask what the 'p' and 'f' are? Are they shortcuts? I've never seen them before (new to MySQL) but very happy - this works perfectly!

Comment: They're called aliases, they allow you to use short names within the query so you don't have to repeat long names like `DB_PropertiesFacilities`.